# BeautifulSoup Soup findall extract only the class data

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-beautifultable

I want to just extract the data in the class line between the< > tags, the html line is:

```
[<h4 class="jobsearch-CompanyReview--heading">ABC</h4>]
```

I am using this code, but it's returning the compete line and I just want the ABC part of the string.

```
company = soup.find_all("h4", class_ ="jobsearch-CompanyReview--heading")
```

How can I just remove the data form the html string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
company = soup.find_all("h4", class_ ="jobsearch-CompanyReview--heading")[0].text
```